# Error while integrating Box in Iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, box-api

I'm trying to integrate Box in iPhone app so that I can upload images on box. I have downloaded the example but its giving me error

here is the error

Error 1.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  
    "_NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey", referenced from:
          +[BoxLocalFileGroup addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:] in Box(BoxLocalFileCache.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
    i386
```

Error2

```
unable to open executable
'/Users/bcod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoxSDK-gzgrgayfjmthqlgnomqiuilpvyai/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoxSDK.app/BoxSDK'
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. Where have you downloaded that code (post the link ...)                   2. Where do you want to save/upload your images to your device (photo album or a server ) ?

Comment: i hav downloaded app from http://developers.box.com/onecloud/. I want to upload on box

Comment: try running the project on a device.

Comment: Do u know what is NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey?

Comment: No. I tried to find it in project but could not find

Answer (score 0):

if you want to integrating Box in Iphone App download the [sample project](https://www.box.com/s/f4fb94a29092ba33cc45)

Comment: I'm run that sample but when I navigate to link to download box its giving me safari could not find that link. And the same link when I open on pc I'm able to open that page